# New EE 2.8.1 install control panel login error

Tags: control-panel, login

Any suggestions would be most appreciated with a problem I'm having with the control panel login.

I'm creating a brand new site, fresh install of 2.8.1, no modules. When I log in to the control panel it displays an error message that the form has expired. This happens in both FF and Chrome.

After looking around for possible fixes, I've added the following to the config file:

$config['admin_session_type'] = cs
$config['cookie_domain'] = .domain.com

This did not help.

To get around the problem, I have to clear the browser cookies and files each time I start working each day. Once I'm in, if I log out I can usually log back in right away. I've cleared the browser cookies and files after a successful login and can usually log in again, too. So the problem seems to come up after I've been away for awhile.

The other thing I noticed is that I have an .htaccess file to remove index.php from URLs. When I comment out that code, the control panel login works again, regardless of whether I've cleared the browser cache/cookies. I'm using the code directly from the EE docs for removing index.php (http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/remove_index.php.html). However, I have to remove the section about "Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLS" because it cause an internal server error. Here's the code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    #RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
    #RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

    # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I've checked with my host, and the server should support this. I also ran the EE wizard just to confirm, and all looked good from that end.

Do you have an idea what is going on, or advice for what to try? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Did you rename your EE /system directory to something besides "system"? If you did, make sure to adjust your .htaccess file on this line so the RewriteCond will be ignored for the control panel directory. Not sure this is the fix but worth trying.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
```

Comment: I did rename it, but also had it renamed in the htaccess file, too. That was the only change I'd made to the file. Thanks for the idea though.